# Kotlin reflection/dynamic function call in multi-platform environment

Tags: kotlin

Given

```
class X {
    fun f() {...}
    fun g() {...}
    ...
}
```

I would like to call f, g, or other class function by name, which is known dynamically at runtime. This is possible with kotlin-reflection, e.g.

```
val callback : KCallable<*>? = X::class.members.firstOrNull { it.name == predVar }
if (callback != null) {
    callback.call(obj, ...)
```

The only snag here is that my multiplatform application has targets other than JVM. For instance, is kotlin reflection doable in javascript? Certainly, JS is dynamically typed language, thus my question is if it is already implemented there.

Alternatively, I can have a collection, or map of those functions. What would be the most elegant syntax of defining a list of functions, and having them callable dynamically? For example, given several enum type attributes, I can make a bunch of Boolean methods like this

```
var booleanDerivatives = hashMapOf<String, () -> Boolean>(
    "breaksAfterComma" to fun (): Boolean {
        return options[breaksComma] === Breaks.After
    }
    ,"breaksBeforeComma" to fun (): Boolean {
        return options[breaksComma] === Breaks.Before
    }
    ,"breaksAfterLogicalConjunction" to fun (): Boolean {
        return options[breaksAroundLogicalConjunctions] === Breaks.After 
            || options[breaksAroundLogicalConjunctions] === Breaks.BeforeAndAfter
    }
)
```

However, unlike reflection, I seem to have to use string literals, because without reflection there is no mechanism translating a name into a string. Or there is?

Comment: Wouldn't [`expect/actual` keywords](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/platform-specific-declarations.html) help in your case?

Comment: There are two parts of my question, and while Paul answered the first one, the second part is open. I assume your expect/actual hint relates to the first part; that is rolling out DIY implementation of reflection which is standard kotlin reflection in JVM env, and reflection proxy in JS via some sort of dynamic calls. Anyway, I have decided to follow the second venue outlined in my post and create a map of functions, as in the second code snippet. My minor gripe about this solution is that the "names" of the methods are string literals, which is probably not big deal at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-reflection.html), no you can't access methods via reflection in the JS target. You would need to maintain your own collection of [function references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) to achieve what you describe across both JVM and JS targets.